# Problem regarding interface reference variable

Tags: java, interface

I've studied that in case of instance methods, at run time the jvm uses the actual class of instance and in case of class methods the compiler will only look at the declared type of a reference variable not the actual class..

I studied this concept instance method hiding..

And in my proram I've used interface reference variable to store the object of the class and try to access the instance method of the class using this but it raise an error..
 My program is as follows:

```
interface A
{
   void show();
}
class B implements A
 {
   public void show()
   {
      System.out.println("Interface Method");
   }
    void info()
  {
     System.out.println("IN Info");
  }
}
class interDemo
{
   public static void main(String args[])
  {
     A a;
     B b=new B();
      a=b;
      a.show();
      a.info();
  }
}
```

Please help me to understand the conept...

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is telling you that the type `A` does not have a method called `info` defined. This is true: the compiler doesn't know that at *runtime*, the type of `a` will actually be `B`, which does have the `info` method. It would be unsafe to allow the `a.info()` call to actually be compiled and emitted into bytecodes, there's nothing to say that `a` will always be of type `B`.

This is known as [static typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing). In Java and other static-typed languages, you need to "cast" a variable in order to force the compiler to treat it as another type. In this case, you can write `((B) a).info()`.

Answer (score 1):

sjr is correct.  Here's another way to look at it:

You're specifying that a `A` can only `show`.  That means when you have a `A` reference variable, that's all you can do.

That means any class that is willing to `show` can implement that interface.  Clients that need an object to `show` can use an `A` without knowing or caring whether that the underlying class has other methods.  This is a key aspect of the abstraction provided by object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

You might probably want to see this [lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nXKirlUQpA&feature=relmfu) on YouTube. It covers you problem and I hope it will help you.

In short: static type of a is A. After assigning b to a, dynamic type of a is B. So at this point, static type a is A and dynamic type of a is B. Compiler does not follow dynamic types, it only checks static types. So it will not let do anything other then static type will allow.

So in your example if you are using reference of static type A, you can only call methods from class A.

Comment: Thank a lot..My problem is solved now and the concept of static and dynamic type is also clear to me..thank u very much!!

Answer (score 0):

super concept without confusion
 =====================================

2 rules to know from where a method will execute(when super type reference is used to call methods)

NOTE:check "object creation"/"reference assignment" statement for applying rule

**1 RULE:** 1st check the method to be called.If **static/overloaded/single**--then it becomes static polymorphism/static(compiler looks for reference type)---hence **always execute from reference type**

**2 RULE:** check method to be called --**if overridden**--then it becomes **dynamic polymorphism(jvm looks for object type)**---hence always executed from object type(i.e right to new keyword)

for example:

```
super s=new child();

s.play();
```

here 2 cases:

**1st**: check play() is what i.e static(static/overloaded/single method) or dynamic(overridden)

**2nd:** if static it will execute from super i.e reference type leads to compile time polymorphism

if dynamic it will execute from child i.e object type leads to dynamic polymorphism